# Proving that a set of vectors forms an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Q) Let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$. Given a sequence $(\alpha_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$, let

$$x_n = \cos\alpha_ne_{2n}-\sin\alpha_ne_{2n+1}, x_{2n+1} = \sin\alpha_ne_{2n}+\cos\alpha_ne_{2n+1}$$

Prove that $(x_n)$ is also an orthonormal basis of $H$.

I can see that $(x_n)$ is orthonormal but how can I show that it is a basis for $H$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cos(\alpha_n)x_n+sin(\alpha_n)x_{2n+1}=e_{2n}$,  $-sin(\alpha_n)x_n+cos(\alpha_n)x_{2n+1}=e_{2n+1}$.